# Extract all TRUE elements from a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list:

```
lst <- list(list(c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE),
                        c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                        c(TRUE, TRUE)),
           list(c(FALSE, FALSE),
                        c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
                        c(TRUE, TRUE,TRUE)))
```

I want to extract only TRUE element with their index.

The result have to be:

```
[[1]][[1]]
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
[[1]][[3]]
[1] TRUE TRUE
[[2]][[3]]
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: You can try `lapply(lst, function(x) x[sapply(x, function(y) all(y))])`  BTW, you cannot have a return  output like the one you showed.  An option would be to name the list elements `lapply(lst, function(x) {x1 <- setNames(x, seq_along(x)); x1[sapply(x1, all)] })`

Comment: Why do you want this?

Answer (score 1):

We loop through the nested `list` rename it with sequence and then extract if `all` are TRUE

```
lapply(lst, function(x) {x1 <- setNames(x, seq_along(x)); x1[sapply(x1, all)] })
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$`1`
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE

#[[1]]$`3`
#[1] TRUE TRUE


#[[2]]
#[[2]]$`3`
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

---

Or another option is `modify_depth` from `purrr`, which result in empty list elements if the condition is not satisfied

```
library(purrr)
lst %>%
    modify_depth(2, ~ .x[all(.x)])
```

Comment: It remplace FALSE by lists containing logical(0). How can I remove it?

Comment: @Noura Try `lst %>%  modify_depth(2, ~ .x[all(.x)]) %>% modify_depth(1, ~ .x[lengths(.x)>0])`